# Cookie is not being stored by the browser?

Tags: cookies, cors

I have been involved with a question about cookies. I am working with fastapi and next.js where my goal is when the endpoint is called I want to set_cookie in the response.

Chrome stores it(but not firefox) with the next parameters:

```
response.set_cookie(key="sessionID", value=str(id), expires=3600*2, samesite='None', secure=True, httponly=True)
```

In my local environment I am running in https both the back and the front but it seems strange to me that in firefox it is not saved. When I want to get the cookie from the header in the back, it does not receive it either, even though it exists on the client side (chrome is the exception with those cookie parameters).

CORS admits the domain 'https://localhost:3000'. in the request the credentials is also

```
const backurl = https://127.0.0.1:8000/authcookie?ip=${ip};
const settings = {
                   method: 'GET',headers:{ 
                                'Accept': 'application/json',
                                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                                },
                   credentials: 'include'};
const response = await fetch(backurl,settings)
```

I think it has something to be with the domain?

Comment: In Chrome, `SameSite=None` also requires the cookie to be set with the `Secure` attribute. You'll need a domain name and a TLS certificate for this to work.

Comment: I used mkcert to run on https://*.project.com:3000 the front and the back is running also in https://127.0.0.1:8000.

Comment: The backend (i.e. the server that instructs browser to create the cookie in question) must be served over `https`.

Comment: it does, backend on https://127.0.0.1:8000 and front at https://www.proyecto.com:3000

Comment: You're not making any sense. If the backend is only accessible via an IP (`127.0.0.1`, according to your latest comment), how can it be served over `https`?

Comment: I used mkcert to have the certificate to be runned on https locally

Comment: Ok. But are you setting the cookie with the `Secure` attribute too?